# Real time ranking django scalability issue

Tags: python, django, caching, scaling

I am making a real time sports ranking application using django and Postgressql and my performance time seems to be alright as of one user. However, I use save signals to update related models entirely without any cache. I was wondering how I could maintain the real time ranking and updating aspect but take the load off of my server and database. I have looked into django-channels, PUSHER, and redis but am unsure of where to go. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i dont understand what your question is... none of those alternatives would necessarily "take the load off your server" ... what do you even mean when you say "take the load off my server"?  why do you think that you will run into scaling issues using your current method?

Comment: I am afraid concurrent requests and utilization of my database will cause it to delay significantly?

Comment: and is this just some gut feeling? or you have some measurments to back this up? also what does "delay significantly" mean? 1 second is a ton of time to a PC ... but its pretty inconsequential to a human.  a pretty smart guy once said "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: I second @JoranBeasley. My experience of Django and Postgressql databases are that they are fast and robust. If you haven't actually experienced any delay in production then I wouldn't be concerned.